# Is there a way to stop in a Blazor component method until a boolean is set?

Tags: events, blazor-server-side, semaphore

This is for Blazor Server version 7. I have a situation where the user is deciding to navigate to another page on the site when they have entered fields on a form and have not saved them.

I am using `<NavigationLock ConfirmExternalNavigation="@_hasUnsavedChanges"                 OnBeforeInternalNavigation="OnBeforeInternalNavigation" />` to ask the user "Are you sure?" in `OnBeforeInternalNavigation()`.

In that method I display a popup component. Once it is displayed, I want to stop execution in that method until the user clicks the Yes or No button. Once that is clicked I want to then resume execution in that method , calling `context.PreventNavigation()` if they clicked No.

First off, is this a bad idea? The page logically is synchronous at this point where the only thing they can do on the page is click yes or no.

Second, how can I do this? Are events the best approach?

Comment: See your other later question for the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76104575/blazor-navigationlock-asking-twice.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I agree, but leaving this question up for others who will ask the same.

Comment: I've added a generic answer as most people won't be using DX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a single page demonstration using a Bootstrap modal and the `TaskCompletionSource` class.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div class="@_dialogCss" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Exit Page</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @onclick=this.Cancel></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Do you really want to leave me?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick=this.Navigate>Navigate</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.Cancel>Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<NavigationLock OnBeforeInternalNavigation=this.OnNavigation />

<style>
    .show-dialog {display:block; }
</style>

@code {
    private bool _showDialog;
    private string _dialogCss => _showDialog ? "modal show-dialog" : "modal";

    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _taskCompletionSource = new();

    private async Task OnNavigation(LocationChangingContext context)
    {
        if (!await this.ShowDialogAsync())
            context.PreventNavigation();
    }

    private Task<bool> ShowDialogAsync()
    {
        _showDialog = true;
        _taskCompletionSource = new();
        // Queue a Render Request
        StateHasChanged();
        // returns the Task associated with the TaskCompletionSource instance
        // this is a running Task that the caller can await
        return _taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    private Task CloseDialogAsync(bool navigate)
    {
        _showDialog = false;
        // Sets the Task to completed
        _taskCompletionSource.SetResult(navigate);
        // Queue a Render Request
        StateHasChanged();
        return _taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    private Task Navigate()
        => CloseDialogAsync(true);

    private Task Cancel()
        => CloseDialogAsync(false);
}
```