# Blazor <NavigationLock> asking twice

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

So I added:

```
<NavigationLock ConfirmExternalNavigation="@IsDirty"
                OnBeforeInternalNavigation="OnBeforeInternalNavigation" />
```

and the following code:

```
/// <summary>
/// true if a field has been edited and not saved. So the data is dirty.
/// </summary>
private bool _hasUnsavedChanges;

/// <summary>
/// true if the user has discarded changes or we're in submit. Either way, don't care about unsaved changes.
/// </summary>
private bool _ignoreChanges;

/// <summary>
/// true if the form is logically dirty. So unsaved changes and not ignoring them.
/// </summary>
private bool IsDirty => _hasUnsavedChanges && !_ignoreChanges;

private async Task OnBeforeInternalNavigation(LocationChangingContext context)
{
    if (!IsDirty)
        return;

    _popupDiscardNavigateTo = context.TargetLocation;
    context.PreventNavigation();
    await _discardPopup.ShowAsync();
}

async Task DiscardChanges()
{
    // we still have unsaved changes, but set this to let the user navigate away.
    _ignoreChanges = true;
    PopupDiscardVisible = false;
    await _discardPopup.CloseAsync();

    if (_popupDiscardNavigateTo != null)
        Navigation.NavigateTo(_popupDiscardNavigateTo, true);
}

async Task StayOnForm()
{
    _popupDiscardNavigateTo = null;
    PopupDiscardVisible = false;
    await _discardPopup.CloseAsync();
}
```

And it all works up to the end as I want.

1. pop up the Yes/No dialog
2. Users selects yes
3. calls NavigateTo("redirected url")
4. IsDirty == false

And then the problem. I get the browser popup asking again if I want to discard my changes. If I set reload == false in NavigateTo() then I don't get that pop-up, but it then doesn't display the page I'm going to.

And IsDirty == false and IsDirty is being called (set a breakpoint). So what gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First, Answer you question**

You call "context.PreventNavigation();" before asking the user.  This sets the internal prevent navigation flag in the context whatever the user selects.

If you say exit and attempt to internally navigate while already in an attempt to navigate, the second attempt is discarded.  You're already set the prevent navigation flag, so nothing happens.

If you say exit and attempt to navigate externally [force refresh flag set to true], you do navigate, but as you have the external navigation checker set in `NavigationLock` then it pops up the question.

Note: using the forced reload in an application totally resets the SPA.  If you're using in your code logic, you've probably got the logic wrong.

**Second, how to code it to work**

I finally took the plunge and installing the Demo version of DXExpress to see how `DxPopUp` works and answer your question.

`ShowAsync` is a bit of a con.  Most modern popups/Modal dialogs wait at this point and do not return a completed `Task` until they close.  Not so with the DXExpress version: it's opens the dialog and marches on thro; there's no true async behaviour.  It's a bit antiquated!

Your issue is you need to await the result of the Popup outcome in the `OnBeforeInternalNavigation` handler.

To do this you need to create a proper async wrapper for `DxPopUp`: the `TaskCompletionSource` class lets you create and manage a manual task.

Here's a demo page based on the standard DXExpress Server template.

`ShowPopup` creates a new `TaskCompletionSource` instance, opens the PopUp and returns the `Task` associated with the `TaskCompletionSource` instance and completes. `OnNavigation` awaits the returned open `Task`.

When the user clicks on one of the buttons, the handlers close the `PopUp` and complete the `TaskCompletionSource`.  The `Task` associated with this completes, `OnNavigation` stops awaiting and runs to completion.  The returned `bool` tells it whether or not to abort navigation.

All this code is normally wrapped in the popup/dialog implementation.  You can see one of mine here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5286721/A-Simple-Blazor-Modal-Dialog-Implementation

```cs
@page "/"

<h2 class="pb-2">Blazor Components</h2>
<p class="pb-2 mw-1100">
    Our Blazor UI components will help you create intuitive and highly-refined user experiences for both Blazor Server (ASP.NET Core) and Blazor WebAssembly hosting models.
</p>
<div class="pb-2 mw-1100">
    <img class="fit-width" src="images/banner.png" />
</div>

<DxPopup @ref=this._discardPopup>
    <div>Do you really want to leave?</div>
    <DxButton CssClass="popup-button my-1 ms-2" RenderStyle="ButtonRenderStyle.Danger" Text="Leave" Click=this.Exit />
    <DxButton CssClass="popup-button my-1 ms-2" RenderStyle="ButtonRenderStyle.Success" Text="Not Now" Click=this.Cancel />
</DxPopup>

<NavigationLock OnBeforeInternalNavigation=this.OnNavigation />

@code {
    private DxPopup? _discardPopup;
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _taskCompletionSource = new();

    private async Task OnNavigation(LocationChangingContext context)
    {
        if (!await ShowPopUpAsync())
            context.PreventNavigation();
    }

    private Task<bool> ShowPopUpAsync()
    {
        _taskCompletionSource = new();

        if (_discardPopup is not null)
            _discardPopup.ShowAsync();

        // we return the Task from the TaskCompletionSource that is not completed
        return _taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    private async Task Exit()
       => this.ClosePopUpAsync(true);

    private async Task Cancel()
       => this.ClosePopUpAsync(false);

    private async Task ClosePopUpAsync(bool navigate)
    {
        if (_discardPopup is not null)
            await _discardPopup.CloseAsync();

        // sets the TaskCompletionSource to completed.  Any awaiters will now complete
        _taskCompletionSource.SetResult(navigate);
    }
}
```

There's a generic version of this answer using a Bootstrap dialog here - [Is there a way to stop in a Blazor component method until a boolean is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76094763/is-there-a-way-to-stop-in-a-blazor-component-method-until-a-boolean-is-set/76105876#76105876)

Comment: Hopefully this answers this question and the one you posed earlier - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76094763/is-there-a-way-to-stop-in-a-blazor-component-method-until-a-boolean-is-set.  You were barking up the right tree!

Comment: Oh and TaskCompletionSource is a very useful thing to learn about. So thanks for that too.