# How to close a Blazor Webassembly Modal

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor webassembly component for a modal pop-up. So far it works, but it will only close when you click the x button and not when you click off
Here is the code in question

```
@using System.Threading.Tasks;

 

@if (IsVisible)

{

    <div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>

    <div id="myModal " class="modal show" style="display: block">

        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">

                    <h5 class="modal-title">@Title</h5>

                    <button @onclick="() => Close()" type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">

                    </button>

                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">

                    @ChildContent

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

   

 

}

 

 

@code {

   [Parameter]

    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

 

    [Parameter]

    public string Title { get; set; }

 

    [Parameter]

    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

 

    [Parameter]

    public EventCallback<bool> IsVisibleChanged { get; set; }

 

    public async Task Close()

    {

        IsVisible = false;

        await IsVisibleChanged.InvokeAsync(IsVisible);

    }

}
```

What is the extra code I need to get this to close when I click off the modal?
I am using .NET 7 with boostrap 5 css
I can't seem to isolate the backdrop to add a click event to close the modal.

Comment: Have you tried adding '@onclick="() => Close()"' to the "modal-backdrop" div?

Comment: No, that doesn't work

Comment: See this recent answer on Bootstrap Modals - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76105876/13065781

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `@onclick="Close"` to the `.modal` div and `@onclick:stopPropagation` to the `.modal-dialog` div.

```
@using System.Threading.Tasks

@if (IsVisible)
{
    <div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal show" style="display: block;" @onclick="Close">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" @onclick:stopPropagation>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">@Title</h5>

                    <button @onclick="Close" type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    @ChildContent
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> IsVisibleChanged { get; set; }

    public async Task Close()
    {
        await IsVisibleChanged.InvokeAsync(false);
    }
}
```

Also it's not a good idea to do `IsVisible = false;` inside the `Close` method.  A blazor component should not set it's own parameters. Instead let the parent control the `IsVisible` parameter using `@bind-` syntax.

```
<Modal @bind-IsVisible="_isVisible" Title="Modal">TEST</Modal>

@code {
    private bool _isVisible = true;
}

@* which is equal to *@

<Modal IsVisible="_isVisible" IsVisibleChanged="OnIsVisibleChanged" Title="Modal">TEST</Modal>

@code {
    private bool _isVisible = true;

    private void OnIsVisibleChanged(bool isVisible)
    {
        _isVisible = isVisible;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/yvup6lx7)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple Modal Dialog based on your code that has async open/close behaviour:

**ModalDialog.razor**

```cs
@if (_isVisible)
{
    <div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>

    <div id="myModal " class="modal show" @onclick=this.CloseOnBackDropClickAsync style="display: block">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">@this.Title</h5>
                    <button @onclick=this.CloseAsync type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @this.ChildContent
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Title { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool CloseOnBackdropClick { get; set; }

    private bool _isVisible { get; set; }
    private TaskCompletionSource _taskCompletionSource = new();

    public Task OpenAsync()
    {
        _taskCompletionSource = new();
        _isVisible = true;
        StateHasChanged();
        return _taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    public Task CloseAsync()
    {
        _isVisible = false;
        StateHasChanged();
        _taskCompletionSource.SetResult();
        return _taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    public async Task CloseOnBackDropClickAsync()
    {
        if (CloseOnBackdropClick)
            await CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

And **Index.razor**

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<ModalDialog Title="Test Modal" @ref=_modalDialog>
    <div class="pb-3">Close me please</div>
    <div class="pb-3 text-end">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.CloseDialogAsync>Close</button>
    </div>
</ModalDialog>

<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=OpenDialogAsync>Open Dialog</button>
</div>

@code {
    private ModalDialog? _modalDialog;

    private async Task OpenDialogAsync()
    {
        if (_modalDialog is not null)
            await _modalDialog.OpenAsync();

        //This code will not run after the modal has closed
    }

    private async Task CloseDialogAsync()
    {
        if (_modalDialog is not null)
            await _modalDialog.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```