How can I manually show/hide a Modal in Blazor?
How do you manually show a Bootstrap 5 Modal using Javascript as explained in their documentation using this format on Blazor Interactive Server?
const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), options)
// or
const myModalAlternative = new bootstrap.Modal('#myModal', options)


I tried using JSInterop.InvokeAsync while having my JS code in another file located in wwwroot/ that I loaded through the App.razor and I tried loading the module itself through the code block but the new bootstrap boostrap variable was not found for both formats.
Instead I used the BlazorBootstrap library which has the Modal component to show my modal rather than Bootstrap 5. Is there a way to use JSInterop to show/hide the boostrap 5 modal?
@page "/modal"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Blazor code block
@code {

    private async Task Confirm()
    {
     // Call method and pass modal ID param to call
      await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("<<METHOD>>", "exampleModal");
    }


}

JS File
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("exampleModal"), {});
myModal.show();

Would Blazor ElementReference be a better approach for this?
Other related question: Bootstrap modal on Blazor stopped working on .NET 8 RC2 (using JSInterop to open/close)
I expected JSInvoke to call the Javascript code and show my modal but it the errored out saying that bootstrap was not found. I attempted to set it to the window object and I tried exporting a function but both returned the same error.

You don't need JS to do this.

Note:  You should avoid using JS to manipulate DOM elements controlled by Blazor.  It's easy to get the Blazor virtual DOM and the browser display DOM out of sync often resulting in unexpected display results on a re-render.

The Bootstrap model is shown or hidden by changing it's css display property.
Here's a simple implementation using your example code with a little refactoring:
Home.razor:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="m-2">
    <button disabled="@_dialogOpen" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.OpenDialog">Open Dialog</button> 
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade @_dialogCss" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @onclick="this.CloseDialog"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="this.CloseDialog">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private bool _dialogOpen;
    private string _dialogCss => _dialogOpen ? "show" : "hide"; 

    private Task OpenDialog()
    {
        _dialogOpen = true;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task CloseDialog()
    {
        _dialogOpen = false;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

Home.razor.css:
.show {
    display:block;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

You can search SO for different component based implementations.
Here's a recent answer on using off-canvas which is basically the same thing.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76114783/13065781
And building an async Modal component:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76114783/13065781
